# Ranking of Baadur Jobava

Tags: tournament, elo, grandmaster

I wanted to know the ranking of Baadur Jobava after his disastrous tournament in
 Tata Steel. But the only updated ranking list I found got to 2700 Elo and Jobava
 seems to be below this mark now.

Does anyone know the actual ranking and the ELO ?

Comment: http://www.2700chess.com/?per-page=100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today the newest Elo list was published:

http://en.chessbase.com/post/february-2015-ratings-the-fulfillment-of-promise

**48.   Jobava, Baadur 2696**

Comment: Thank you very much! So, Jobava is still under the top 50.